# removing only some of the annotations from an apple map view

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have the following:

```
for location in self.locationsWithinMapFiltered {
  self.mapView.addAnnotation(location)
}
```

but based upon filtering, the user can remove some annotation which do not fulfill their criteria. I have a list of the location_id's to 
remove but there doesn't seem to be a way to get out the location_id from the annotation.

I was thinking of using the coordinate's to determine 
which is which but that seems like a cumbersome way or just removing all and adding only the ones of interest but again pretty cumbersome. Is there a way to efficiently remove a subset of annotations?